# Google Tag Manager (GTM) - how to find out if anonyizeIp (aip) is set

Tags: google-tag-manager

I wonder if there is a possibility to find out if Google Tag Manager (of any site) has the anonymizeIp Flag set or not. I looked into the network traffic but could not find any parameters - neither in the http traffic nor in the cookies which are set by Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can find it in the UA Request URL as "aip" query string parameter. Link to google support pages [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2763052?hl=en)

Look again in the network traffic, if the anonymizeIp field is set to true it will appear as:

"https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&_v=j00&**aip=1**&a=0001..."